# add a key value to object response

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, key

```
  $.post("./bigData.php", {'username': username}, function(response) {

            console.log(response);
            var bigUser = response[username]; // attempt one
            var bigUser2 = username.response; // attempt two

       });
```

My above `response` consoles like below:

```
{"userSumData":[{"id":"slz1","checked":false},{"id":"slz2","checked":false},{"id":"slz3","checked":false},{"id":"slz4","checked":false}, ....."Map":true}
```

My desired result is this:

```
{"steven":{"userSumData":[{"id":"slz1","checked":false},{"id":"slz2","checked":false},{"id":"slz3","checked":false},{"id":"slz4","checked":false}, ....."Map":true}}
```

I have tried dot notation and square bracket after my `response`, all just wipe the data out.

Comment: Now that I see your desired response: `const obj = {steven:response};`. Of course, one has to wonder why you are wrapping your response with an object with a single property in the first place.

Comment: Where do I add this? Doing this, then after console logging obj, my response data is gone

Comment: There are two separate issues here apparently. One is turning the response into the desired result, which is done like StackSlave shows. The other is to deal with async code in general, and I guess there's the usual confusion about the order in which things happen. Also, declaring a `var` and then ending the function is utterly pointless; nothing will ever be able to access that variable; it's gone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are just assigning to a variable, not an Object property. You need to create an Object, then assign your response to a `nameVar` property of that Object, like:

```
$.post('bigData.php', {username: username}, response=>{
  const obj = {[nameVar]:response}; // notice that we are creating an object and assigning it a variable called obj which has a steven property
  console.log(obj[nameVar]);
}, 'json');
```

You should, of course, understand asynchronous activity. In other words, if you want to use that `obj` it must be used with the function body that contains your `response`. It will not be available outside that. You can always create a `Promise` structure, but that is really just a syntactical indention reducing implementation of the same thing.

Comment: Thanks, however before this my console.log(response) has data, after I do this it turns to object object

Comment: Your response is probably a String. I'll set the `'json'` argument. Test in a minute.

Comment: Got it, it's working now - however steven is from a variable i.e. username, anyway to handle for that as a var? i.e. username.response

Comment: I changed it to how you probably want. Replace `nameVar` with your variable. I will tell you from a design standpoint it may not make sense to just have a property of an object as an unknown. How do you get the name of the unknown later? Loop over the Object? Objects that are not `instanceof Array` do not have a specific order.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's rather simple if I get it right. Try this `...` notation. If it isn't what you want, please comment it out :)

```js
const obj = {"userSumData":[{"id":"slz1","checked":false},{"id":"slz2","checked":false},{"id":"slz3","checked":false},{"id":"slz4","checked":false}],"Map":true};

const name = "steven"
const newObj = {[name]: {...obj}}

console.log(newObj)
```

Comment: Thanks however when I implement this in my response, my response data disappears

Answer (score 1):

First of all i think that you have JSON format of your data, to convert it into Object you have to use **JSON.parse(response)**;

You are trying to mutate your response object, don't do it, instead create a new object with the same properties. If i correctly understand your question, you can create a new object using

ES6: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

```
    let my_object = { inside_object : { steven: { ...response  } }}
```

ES5: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

```
    let my_object = { inside_object : { steven: Object.assign({}, response) }}
```

Comment: What would 'inside_object' be referring to here? I just have the response object and the name, i.e. steven I want to use as key

Comment: It would be reffeing to a new object that you will be created after { ...response  }. Every time you get a new http request you will create a new object.

Oh, i think i have got it you have VARIABLE - steven, if so you could use ES6 brackets [yourKeyVariable]: someValueArray,